# ESLint/TypeScript/Prettier indentation problem when JSX is used for in-line component declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint

When ESLint and Prettier encounter the following code:

```
@classDecorator([
  {
    initialState: ({ mutation }) => (
      <>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => mutation({ variables: { param1: 'success' } })}> // Line 33
          Test Mutation Success
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => mutation({ variables: { param1: 'error' } })}> // Line 36
          Test Mutation Fail
        </button>
      </>
    ),
    successState: () => 'Success - component state changed',
  },
])
```

it generates the following errors:

```
  33:9  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 8  react/jsx-indent
  36:9  error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 8  react/jsx-indent
```

Additionally, when `eslint` is run with `--fix`, it does this:

```
@classDecorator([
  {
    initialState: ({ mutation }) => (
      <>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => mutation({ variables: { param1: 'success' } })}>
    Test Mutation Success
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => mutation({ variables: { param1: 'error' } })}>
    Test Mutation Fail
        </button>
      </>
    ),
    successState: () => 'Success - component state changed',
  },
])
```

and then gives the following errors:

```
  33:9   error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 8   react/jsx-indent
  33:94  error  Expected indentation of 10 space characters but found 4  react/jsx-indent
  34:5   error  Insert `······`                                          prettier/prettier
  36:9   error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 8   react/jsx-indent
  36:92  error  Expected indentation of 10 space characters but found 4  react/jsx-indent
  37:1   error  Insert `······`                                          prettier/prettier
```

Here is the `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'jsx-a11y',
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect' // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
    }
  },
  rules: {
    // Place to specify ESLint rules. Can be used to overwrite rules specified from the extended configs
    // e.g. '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': ['error', { prefixWithI: 'always' }],
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/require-await': 'off',
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': ['error', 2],
    'react/jsx-indent': ['error', 2, { checkAttributes: true, indentLogicalExpressions: true }],
  },
};
```

Without the `'react/jsx-indent': ['error', 2, { checkAttributes: true, indentLogicalExpressions: true }],` line, the exact same effect is observed.

Comment: Use `<React.Fragment>` instead of `<>`?

Comment: Tried it! The `--fix` actually removed `<React.Fragment>` and replaced it with `<>`, and it also created some new and exciting indentation issues. Although it did put the text nodes in the right place, it changed the indents on lines 33 and 36 to be 2 spaces (basically what it was doing to the two text nodes before).

Comment: Anyway, if you are using prettier, you should remove all ESLint styling rules. They will conflict. Or remove prettier. Prettier doesn't exactly help code readability.

Comment: Oh I see! Does one not use the two together? I thought they were meant to be complimentary!

Comment: They can be used together but not if you have defined conflicting rules. Why would you test things like indentation by ESLint (the `indent` rule) if prettier rules enforce it too? Just disable these rules and keep only the functionality rules (e.g. unused variables, use before define etc.)